# how can we print custom value for a list value

Tags: python

I have to take input from values as shown below

```
def abc():
    d = [1, 2, 3]

    if d:       
     print('select')  
     i = 0
    while i < len(d):
        output = d[i].join(d) +'is value'
        print(output)
        i=i+1
        if i < len(d):
         print('or')
        # print ('select',+str(output))
abc()
```

what am I expecting is to print the output as below and to write the same in excel using xlswriter  :

> select 1 is value or 2 is value or 3 is value

but I am getting the error shown below:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d[i]` is an integer, there is no join function for an integer, you can just append it to the string directly

```
f'{d[i]} is value'
```

If you did want to use a join, and do the entire thing in one go..

```
print('select ', ' or '.join([f'{val} is value' for val in d]))
```

Comment: @GeethaAnand - its an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) - You could use `str(d[i]) + 'is value'` instead if you'd prefer - The "is value" is purely a string for your output, it is not syntax related

Comment: Thanks @sayse, appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Sayse...Here....we are getting "or" only for first two values in list...if i want to print "or" for last value also? then what would be your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you another function,in case you are interested in a distinct approach:

```
chain = ['select '] #initial value to print
for i in d:
    if str(i).isdigit():
        val = (str(i) +' is value')
        chain.append(val)
        #['select ', '1 is value', '2 is value', '3 is value']      

place = chain[1:-1] #skip first and last
replace = []
for insertion in place:
    replace.append(insertion+ ' or ')

chain[1:-1] = replace
print(''.join(chain))
#select 1 is value or 2 is value or 3 is value
```

If you want it in a function:

```
def abc():
    d = [1, 2, 3]
    chain = ['select '] #initial value to print
    for i in d:
        if str(i).isdigit():
            val = (str(i) +' is value')
            chain.append(val)
            #['select ', '1 is value', '2 is value', '3 is value']
    place = chain[1:-1] #skip first and last
    replace = []
    for insertion in place:
        replace.append(insertion+ ' or ')

    chain[1:-1] = replace
    return ''.join(chain)
```